# Is there a way to identify which camera is plugged in?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have two similar cameras (ps3 camera) and I'm interested in identifying which one is plugged in every time. I use opencv 2.4 and c++ to capture video. The camera is connected to the computer via usb

Comment: You forgot to mention what OS do you use?

Comment: I use ubuntu, but I think that this has nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenCV `cv::VideoCapture()` API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) does not provide a cross-platform way of identifying a particular camera.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can connect them to different usb ports, and give them different name based on this (with help of udev), like here for usb<->to serial https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters